# HoloEverywhere SeekBar ClassCastException

Tags: java, android, android-holo-everywhere

I am using the SeekBar class provided by HoloEverywhere. I have the following imports:

```
import org.holoeverywhere.widget.SeekBar;
import org.holoeverywhere.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;
```

I get no preliminary errors or warnings, but when I compile, I get a class cast exception on the following line:

```
sectionTimeElapsedSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sectionTimeElapsedSeekBar);
```

Here is the corresponding XML:

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sectionTimeElapsedSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/startOrPauseTimerButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:max="2100" />
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change to:

```
<org.holoeverywhere.widget.SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/sectionTimeElapsedSeekBar"
        ...
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

Extend activity from org.holoeverywhere.app.Activity.

Answer (score 0):

try importing:

```
import android.widget.SeekBar;
```

instead of

```
import org.holoeverywhere.widget.SeekBar;
```

Comment: Aren't you using the default SeekBar instead of the holoeverywhere SeekBar if you import it this way?